# Getting value from query builder select count result in Laravel

Tags: php, postgresql, laravel

I have a query builder in Laravel controller to get total value of total select table row from database, and I want to get the result value, but the result always give me an array result, and I've tried to access the value from the array but I still cant get the value

Here's the query builder:

```
$total = DB::select(DB::raw("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM hstmemb WHERE period = '".$bonperiod."' AND totbns <> 0 AND paytype = 'S'"));
$getbonus[0]->total = $total;
```

The result I get is an array object, but I want to get just the count result in int number.

Answer (score 0):

Use DB table with count function.

```
$total = DB::table('hstmemb')->where('period', $bonperiod)->where('totbns', '<>', 0)->where('paytype', 'S')->count();
```

Comment: what if i have query like this `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT loccd, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY loccd) num FROM bouyaa where period = '".$bonperiod."'' and totbns <> 0 and paytype = 'S') inn WHERE inn.num = 1`